# Overlap percentage of NMDS using metaMDS in vegan package in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlap, vegan, multi-dimensional-scaling

How do I calculate the percent overlap of my 95% confidence interval ellipses in my NMDS plots? I used the 'vegan' package and my code is posted below.

The data sheet columns are by species and the rows are by plot # 1-16 which are categorized into four groups as seen in the NMDS attached below. Here is a few rows and columns as an example. Ten column examples are here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gf5llxm986i3kld/mydata.txt?dl=0
I would love to sort by "Treatment" so that I have four ellipses

```
  Plot   BHW   YHW   Clown   Tobacco   Unwrasse   DuskDam   YTD   Beau   BridG   GoldG   
 ------ ----- ----- ------- --------- ---------- --------- ----- ------ ------- -------- 
     1    20     0       0         0          0         0     0      0       2        0  
     2    15     0       0         0          0         0     0      0       4        3  
     3    10     0       0         0          0         0     0      0       3        3  
     4     6     0       0         0          0         0     0      0       3        2  
     5    33     0       0         0          0         0     0      0       0        7  
     6     7     0       0         0          0         0     0      0       1        0  
     7    27     1       0         0          0         0     0      0       2        3  
     8    22     0       0         0          0         0     0      0       0        3
```

The code used to produce the NMDS plots is:

```
abund_fish_06_01to_06_03<-abund_fish[abund_fish$Date>="2016-06-01" &abund_fish$Date<="2016-06-03",]
    abund_fish_06_01to_06_03_rn<- abund_fish_06_01to_06_03[,2:62] #to remove date and plot

sol <- metaMDS(abund_fish_06_01to_06_03_rn, distance = "bray", k = 3, trymax = 100) 
NMDS = data.frame(MDS1 = sol$points[,1], MDS2 = 
sol$points[,2],group=MyMeta$Treatment)
NMDS.mean=aggregate(NMDS[,1:2],list(group=NMDS$group),mean)
veganCovEllipse<-function (cov, center = c(0, 0), scale = 1, npoints = 100) 
{
theta <- (0:npoints) * 2 * pi/npoints
Circle <- cbind(cos(theta), sin(theta))
t(center + scale * t(Circle %*% chol(cov)))
}

df_ell <- data.frame()
for(g in levels(NMDS$group)){
df_ell <- rbind(df_ell, cbind(as.data.frame(with(NMDS[NMDS$group==g,],veganCovEllipse(cov.wt(cbind(MDS1,MDS2),wt=rep(1/length(MDS1),length(MDS1)))$cov,center=c(mean(MDS1),mean(MDS2)))))
                            ,group=g))}
nmds6163bw<-ggplot(data = NMDS, aes(MDS1, MDS2)) + geom_point(aes(color = 
group, shape = group), stroke =1.25,size=2.5) +
theme_bw()+
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
    axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold")
 )+
theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 14)
)+
theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 14)
)+
geom_path(data=df_ell, aes(x=MDS1, y=MDS2, color = group, linetype=group), size =1)+
scale_shape_manual(name = "Treatment", labels = c("10m Control", "20m Control", "March Outplant", "June Outplant"), values = c(1, 19, 15,0)) +
scale_colour_manual(name = "Treatment", labels = c("10m Control", "20m Control", "March Outplant", "June Outplant"), values = c("grey50", "grey50", "black", " black "))+
scale_linetype_manual(name = "Treatment", labels = c("10m Control", "20m Control", "March Outplant", "June Outplant"), values = c(2, 1, 1, 2))
nmds6163bwnl<-nmds6163bw+theme(legend.position="none") +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

`

Below is a resultant NMDS plots.

[image: NMDS plot]

Comment: Could you please provide the data in a reproducible format, like `dput()`? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Or create a new example using builtin data. Also the few columns rows you showed are incomplete (missing date, etc) and I don't think there would be enough rows to reproduce this anyway.

Comment: Nice question. I once looked at how to do this, but analytic equations were not quite simple for ellipses with non-parallel marginal axes. It is doable, and I will add it to vegan if nice code is proposed.

Comment: @Hack-R Formatted Data (see above)